# Accessing Springfox local swagger ui triggers HttpServletRequests

Tags: java, spring, http, swagger

I have a spring boot project with some rest endpoints and a swagger ui page. I am able to access the swagger page successfully at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ with springfox-swagger-ui & springfox-swagger2 2.9.2 (or at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ when using springfox-boot-starter 3.0.0). As part of my security configuration, I have a simple authentication filter that can be used to validate api keys the user will be able to enter in the swagger page.

However, my problem is that every time I go to the swagger page it automatically calls the attemptAuthentication() method in my filter (and multiple times). This should not happen. It should only get called when I input the key information & then click authorize on the page.

The HttpServletRequest attempting authentication is the same type for all 10 requests. All of the requests being triggered are GET on different URIs. This is the request type

```
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest]
```

And these are all of the URI's:

/swagger-ui/

/swagger-ui/springfox.css

/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css

/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js

/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js

/swagger-ui/springfox.js

/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

/swagger-resources/configuration/security

/swagger-resources

/v2/api-docs

SimpleAuthFilter

```
public class SimpleAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public SimpleAuthFilter(final RequestMatcher req) {
    super(req)
    setAuthenticationManager(new MyAuthManager())
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    // -> Getting called here when visting swagger page
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse, final FilterChain chain, final Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }
}
```

MyAuthManager

```
private class MyAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Bad auth");
    }
}
```

MySecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity sec) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(filter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            ...
            ;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleAuthFilter filter() {
    RequestMatcher match = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
    return new SimpleAuthFilter(match);
  }
}
```

SwaggerConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("MyProject"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .enableUrlTemplating(true)
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singleton(new ApiKey("mykey", "Authorization", "header")))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singleton(context()));
  }
  
  public SecurityContext context() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
             .securityReferences(securityReferences())
             .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
             .build();
  }

  public List<SecurityReference> securityReferences() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("mykey", new AuthorizationScope[]{new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything")}));
  }
}
```

I was thinking the issue might be something to do with needing to configure resource handlers by extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport but, every time I tried that the swagger page had issues. Or I might need to look at somehow excluding those URI paths with multiple antMatcher() ?

Ive tried using different swagger dependencies, moving the filter location in the HttpSecurity configuration, resource handlers, view controllers, but nothing has worked for me.

I am using spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-security 2.3.4 & spring-boot-starter-validation 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a partial answer which is that the RequestMatcher used to create the filter in MySecurityConfig should instead be specific to ONLY the endpoints and not be `/**` which will cause the filter to actually attempt authentication even when visiting the swagger page.

Problem with using an AntPathRequestMatcher is if my endpoints do not have a prefixed pattern for example,

/endpoint1

/endpoint2